# Announcing Apps to the Public

Tags: support

I believe this has been discussed before but I can't find the question/answer so I'll ask it officially here:

**Now that v1.0 is released, it's OK to announce our apps to the general public, correct?**

This would be including but not limited to blogs, airplane-towed banners, screaming from rooftops, car and bus skins, and large garish tattoos...

Comment: Oh... I certainly hope so, since I already mentioned it on Twitter and my blog.  Also, pics of the tattoos, please.  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is OK to announce [app]s.

... I'd hold off on tattoos personally, but they're not *banned* per-say... :)